# Finding the first unique occurrence in file

Tags: python, regex

In a log file, there are .csv files and I need to find only one occurrence of that file name with file extension.

Example:
Abcde.csv

I have this below line but it finds all the csv files with filepath within the words “Importing file ./“ and “.”. It also isn’t considering “.” full stop in the sentence and printing the next line.

```
for result in re.findall(‘Importing file ./(.*?).’, fp.read(), re.S):
```

Is there any way I can get only the filename with file extension.

Current result:

```
/user/path/abcde.csv
Line number :1235
```

Expectation:

```
abcde.csv
```

Update-
Current line :

Line number 12983: Importing file /user/path/abcde.csv.

Comment: In current case split it by '/' and get the last index it will give you the file name but as you mentioned find All will get all the csv file names were logged. Just get the first index of the result provided by findAll function and split it to get the csv file name

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a line in the file that should result in abcde.csv

Comment: Scrapper142 I have edited the post with the current line being displayed

Comment: Still unclear. If there are multiple csv filenames in the log file and
you want to find only one, please provide more lines which include
extra csv filenames you want to discard with some logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example string

> Line number 12983: Importing file /user/path/abcde.csv.

You can use:

```
\bImporting file (?:/[^/\n]+)*/([^/\n]+\.csv)\.
```

- `\bImporting file`  Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `/[^/\n]+` Match `/` and 1 or more chars other than `/` or a newline
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `/` Match a `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^/\n]+\.csv` Match 1+ chars other than `/` or a newline and then `.csv`
- `)\.` Close group 1 and match the trailing dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KXwMld/1)

Example

```
for result in re.findall(r"\bImporting file (?:/[^/\n]+)*/([^/\n]+\.csv)\.", fp.read()):
    print(result)
```

Output

```
abcde.csv
```

Comment: Hey! I remember commenting on this but my account got locked by then. This answer worked for my scenario. Thank you!

Comment: I had another similar situation with the below line:  linenumber 1234: events were written to file ‘/usr/path/filename.GMF’ (threshold 0).

Comment: @rashxxx It depends on how specific you want the pattern to be, for example like https://regex101.com/r/Sp8zHa/1

Comment: Ohh I’m judging trying to figure how to use this website. Seems like a useful website. Thanks for sharing that link!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `re.search` to find the path, like so

```py
filename = re.search('Importing file (/.+)*/(.*.csv)', fp.read()).group(2)
```

Here, there are multiple things happening:

- `re.search` searches a string for a certain regex
- `.+` matches one or more characters (any characters)
- `.*` matches any number of characters (could be none)
- `(/.+)*` matches any form of '/aaa/bbb/ccc/etc', by matching a slash followed by characters any number of times
- `(.*.csv)` matches a csv file name such as 'anyfilename.csv'
- `group(2)` means it finds only the text in the second set of parentheses in the matched string, in this case `.*.csv`, the filename

Also note I took out the `re.S` flag so the filename can't contain newlines

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
for result in re.findall(r'Importing file \./(?:.*/)?(.+)\.', fp.read()):
    print(result.group(1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4qJLxQ/2). *Details*:

- `Importing file \./` - a `Importing file ./` string
- `(?:.*/)?` - an optional occurrence of any text ending with `/` (to get to the last `/` on the line)
- `(.+)` - Group 1 (the result): one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Comment: Thank you this works if the csv file is in the current directory. Appreciate it!

Comment: @rashxxx I missed the fact you need to check for a trailing `.`, added right now.